# Economical solution for time synchronization (+/-200ns)?

Tags: pcie, gps, measurement-devices

I'm looking for hardware (or dedicated server options) that enable time synchronization to within +/-200ns of UNIX Epoch. I've started looking at GPS referenced bus level timing (PCIe) in the $2500 range. While cost is a significant factor, I'm very interested in the value of support and strength of the API.

Comment: Could you specify some more requirements to narrow the process down? For example, what PCIe lane size do you need (x1, x8, x16)? What external connections are you using?

Comment: @Adam At this stage, I have not selected the server hardware, so I can use whatever makes for the best value.

Comment: @Adam Most likely, yes. But it will need to be somewhat future proof. Support and the strength of the API are also very important.